# Extract media from double quote if pregmatch

Tags: php, regex

I am getting file_get_content of a site and it returns me this

```
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="//abc-def- 
ghi.net/reg02/2016/05/31/05/92f24c57-2cb3-42b0-84cb-edad24d7b68f.mp4? 
secure=1"><meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4"><meta 
property="og:video:width" content="540"><meta property="og:video:height" 
content="960"><meta property="fb:app_id" content="682659535154406">
```

As you can see  **content** is written multiple times. what i want to do is if i search for **.mp4** and if found in some **content** then it will copy the whole data inside that double quote
For example in the above code it will extract and give me

```
//mpak-suse1.akamaized.net/reg02/2016/05/31/05/92f24c57-2cb3-42b0-84cb-edad24d7b68f.mp4?secure=1
```

I am pretty confused about how to do that so haven't coded anything.
What i found was an alternate solution to do is using get string between function

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
$string = " ".$string;
$ini = strpos($string,$start);
if ($ini == 0) return "";
$ini += strlen($start);   
$len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
$link = get_string_between($output, '<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="', '">');
```

But it doesnt look very reliable.and the thing i am asking for could help many others in different projects.if anyone could please enlighten the topic

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended by the majority of StackOverflow volunteers to use a dom parser like DomDocument or similar to effectively/reliably parse html data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FmBdl))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="//abc-def- 
ghi.net/reg02/2016/05/31/05/92f24c57-2cb3-42b0-84cb-edad24d7b68f.mp4? 
secure=1"><meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4"><meta 
property="og:video:width" content="540"><meta property="og:video:height" 
content="960"><meta property="fb:app_id" content="682659535154406"><meta property="test" nocontent="bad">
HTML;

$dom=new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("meta") as $meta) {
    if ($meta->hasAttribute('content') && strpos($content = $meta->getAttribute('content'), '.mp4')) {
        $result[] = $content;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '//abc-def- 
ghi.net/reg02/2016/05/31/05/92f24c57-2cb3-42b0-84cb-edad24d7b68f.mp4? 
secure=1',
)
```

*For the record, yes, I know about testing for `false` with `strpos()` because offset `0` and `false` loosely evaluate to `false`, but logically, if the `content` value begins with `.mp4` it isn't going to be a usable/qualifying value.